# How to modify the size of a <g> (SVG element)?

Tags: css, svg, recharts

I can not seem to succeed at modifying the size of my  element that is rendered inside a recharts graph as X axis. I want it to be 20px height and width. I couldn't even succeed by making modifications in the console css to the element. Could anyone help me out?

Here's the element:

```html
    <svg
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer',  }} width="20px" height="20px"
        >
          <g transform={`translate(10,10)`} fill="green" stroke="green">
            <path
              fill="current"
              fillRule="evenodd"
              d="M8,0 C3.58862306,0 0,3.58862306 0,8 C0,12.4113769 3.58862306,16 8,16 C12.4113769,16 16,12.4113769 16,8 C16,3.58862306 12.4113769,0 8,0 Z M12.0546875,6.3046875 L7.72131347,10.6379394 C7.59130859,10.7679443 7.42065431,10.833374 7.25,10.833374 C7.07934569,10.833374 6.90869141,10.7679443 6.77868653,10.6379394 L4.61206056,8.47131347 C4.35131837,8.21069338 4.35131837,7.78930663 4.61206056,7.52868653 C4.87268066,7.26794434 5.29394531,7.26794434 5.5546875,7.52868653 L7.25,9.22399903 L11.1120606,5.36206056 C11.3726807,5.10131837 11.7939453,5.10131837 12.0546875,5.36206056 C12.3153076,5.62268066 12.3153076,6.04394531 12.0546875,6.3046875 Z"
              transform="translate(.5)"
            />
          </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Since the whole SVG is the `g` why not size the SVG instead. Please provide a [mcve] of this NOT working.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've just added a snippet to make it clearer. I tried changing the size of the svg but it did not work

Comment: Works for me is you specify the dimensions in the CSS and not the style tag

Comment: @Paulie_D I can't seem to make it work

Comment: You can add a viewBox to the svg element. For example <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" In this case you will need to remove the transformations both of the group and the path and also remove the stroke. If you need the stroke you will need a diferent viewBox="-.5 -.5 17 17". Otherwise half of the stroke will fall outside the svg canvas

Answer (score 2):

As **@enxaneta** recommended, a negative viewBox offset like  `viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 17 17"` is a straight forward solution.

Alternatively, you could scale your `<g>` (or your path) like so:

```css
.svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <g transform="scale(0.94117647)" transform-origin="8 8" stroke-width="1" fill="green" stroke="green">
    <path  d="M8,0 C3.58862306,0 0,3.58862306 0,8 C0,12.4113769 3.58862306,16 8,16 C12.4113769,16 16,12.4113769 16,8 C16,3.58862306 12.4113769,0 8,0 Z M12.0546875,6.3046875 L7.72131347,10.6379394 C7.59130859,10.7679443 7.42065431,10.833374 7.25,10.833374 C7.07934569,10.833374 6.90869141,10.7679443 6.77868653,10.6379394 L4.61206056,8.47131347 C4.35131837,8.21069338 4.35131837,7.78930663 4.61206056,7.52868653 C4.87268066,7.26794434 5.29394531,7.26794434 5.5546875,7.52868653 L7.25,9.22399903 L11.1120606,5.36206056 C11.3726807,5.10131837 11.7939453,5.10131837 12.0546875,5.36206056 C12.3153076,5.62268066 12.3153076,6.04394531 12.0546875,6.3046875 Z" ></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Edit: correct scaling value

As @Carsten Massmann has pointed out it should be:
The scaling factor **0.94117647** is the result of
16/17 (original svg width / svg width + stroke-width)

`transform-origin="8 8"` ensures we're scaling from the center of our viewBox.

Another workaround might be to set **overflow to visible** to avoid any cropping:

```css
.svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<svg overflow="visible" class="svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path  stroke-width="1" fill="green" stroke="green" d="M8,0 C3.58862306,0 0,3.58862306 0,8 C0,12.4113769 3.58862306,16 8,16 C12.4113769,16 16,12.4113769 16,8 C16,3.58862306 12.4113769,0 8,0 Z M12.0546875,6.3046875 L7.72131347,10.6379394 C7.59130859,10.7679443 7.42065431,10.833374 7.25,10.833374 C7.07934569,10.833374 6.90869141,10.7679443 6.77868653,10.6379394 L4.61206056,8.47131347 C4.35131837,8.21069338 4.35131837,7.78930663 4.61206056,7.52868653 C4.87268066,7.26794434 5.29394531,7.26794434 5.5546875,7.52868653 L7.25,9.22399903 L11.1120606,5.36206056 C11.3726807,5.10131837 11.7939453,5.10131837 12.0546875,5.36206056 C12.3153076,5.62268066 12.3153076,6.04394531 12.0546875,6.3046875 Z" ></path>
</svg>
```

**Caveats:** your icon will be displayed larger than your original design and might cause layout inconsistencies when used with other elements that fit the 16x16 boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for these very interesting points! I just played around with it a bit more and realised that the scaling factor should indeed be `16/17 = 0.94117647` (instead of 0.9375) as the total size of the icon with `stroke-width="1"` would be `16+1` and it needs to be scaled down to `16`.

Comment: @Carsten Massmann: thanks for checking this! I revised the answer.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, this little issue was driving me insane! It works perfectly @herrstrietzel

Answer (score 0):

If it will be useful to you, I found svg similar to yours and I demonstrated how you can add styles

```css
svg {
 background: #479840;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
path {
 filter: invert(99%) sepia(99%) saturate(2%) hue-rotate( 205deg) 
       brightness(110%) contrast(100%);
}
```

```html
<svg height="44" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="44" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="m10 15.586-3.293-3.293-1.414 1.414L10 18.414l9.707-9.707-1.414-1.414z"></path></svg>
```